# Proof for sup and inf of $A=\{1-1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}⊂\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=\{1-1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}⊂\mathbb{Q}$

I want to proof the supremum and infimum of the set $A$ is. I can intuitively see that it is $\sup(A)=1$ and $\inf(A)=0$.

I know I need to proof that 1 is in the upper bound and 0 is in the lower bound, and then that it is the smallest upper and largest lower bound.

The upper bound of $A$ is $1$, as $1/n$ tends to 0 when $n$ gets larger. And the lower bound is $0$ for the same reason.

But how do I reason/proof that they are the smallest upper and largest lower bound?

Comment: Suppose that there is a smaller upper bound (resp. larger lower bound) and arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Can you use the result that $a$ is the supremum of $A$ if and only if $a$ is an upper bound for $A$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have $(a-\varepsilon,a]\cap A\neq\emptyset$? (similar result for $\inf(A)$).

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that for all $x<1$, $x$ is not an upper bound of $A$, which means there exists some $a\in A$ such that $a>x$. Finding this $a$ will have to depend on $x$.

Similarly, you want to show that for all $x>0$, $x$ is not a lower bound of $A$, meaning there exists some $a\in A$ such that $a<x$. Finding this $a$ will be easy.

Comment: So if I let $a=1$ I have $1>x$. Is writing this (in a more proper way) a correct way of showing that $sup(A)=1$?

Comment: @Sirmimer Well, you can't take $a=1$, since $1\not\in A$.

Comment: I thought $A=[0,1]$ as $1/n$ approaches 0 and therefore you have $1-0=1$?

Comment: @Sirmimer $1/n$ approaches $0$, but there is no value of $n$ for which it equals $0$. So $1$ is not a member of the set $A$.

Answer (score 1):

We assert that $A$ is bounded, as its terms are clearly in the interval $(0,1)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $s=\sup A$ and $d=\inf A$. Given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N_0 > \dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$. We have $1-\varepsilon < 1-\dfrac{1}{N_0}$, i.e., $1-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for the set $A$ for some $\varepsilon >0$, and thus $s=1$. On the other hand, suppose $d \neq 0$. Then there are two cases to consider: $d>0$ and $d<0$.

Suppose $d<0$. Since $d$ is the infimum of $A$, using the same $\varepsilon$, we have that there exists $\widetilde{a} \in A$ such that $d+\varepsilon > \widetilde{a}$. Setting $\varepsilon = -d > 0$, we have $\widetilde{a} < d-d = 0$, which is absurd since the elements of $A$ are in the interval $(0,1)$.

Now, assuming $d>0$, there exists $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N_1 > -\dfrac{1}{d}$. Thus, $1<1+d<1-\dfrac{1}{N_1} \in A$, which is absurd, as 1 is the smallest upper bound of the set $A$. Therefore, $d=0$.